# Book suggestion on "Banach space geometry for machine learning"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, machine-learning

Is there any book for a Mathematics student who can learn Machine learning in the aspect of Banach space geometry? Or, one can understand the connection between Geometry of Banach spaces and Machine learning? Any suggestions in terms of article, note, book regarding the development of such study is always welcomed.

It will be very much helpful if anyone can suggest a good book which contains the discussion about the topic of Geometry of banach spaces that is required for Machine learning, Neural network such things. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have some evidence that there is a relation between Machine Learning and Geometry of Banach Spaces?  I would be interested to know what it is.

Comment: @GEdgar I have a positive hope since I have seen a presentation video in Youtube on geometry of Banach space in position based cryptography. Still I do not know whether there is a positive answer regarding my query.

Comment: My guess is that any such connection is not worth pursuing unless you already have a nontrivial knowledge of the Geometry of Banach spaces. I also suspect that any such research is something done primarily by those with some expertise in the Geometry of Banach spaces who want to leverage this knowledge in the currently red-hot field of Machine Learning. However, I don't know very much about either subject and maybe there is something to this merger. Nonetheless, my gut reaction is that this is an [everything is a nail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) situation.

Comment: Thank you @DaveL.Renfro for this valuable suggestion to such a beginer like me.